# Умерщвлять, умерщвление — [ш] или [щ]?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Всегда произносил эти слова со звуком Ш и был уверен, что так правильно. Неужели я ошибался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему - да. Там явное Щ.

Щ от Ш отличается не только твердость/мягкостью, но и долготой.
Так вот, если регрессивная ассимиляция по твердости под действием последующего твердого В еще возможна (хотя и не нормирована), то уж долгота в принципе никуда деться не может.

Ну и, конечно, ни Зарва, ни Аванесов не дают оснований полагать, что ваш вариант возможен.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, у Аванесова и на Грамоте проверил, перед тем как задать вопрос, и, к сожалению, не нашёл помет.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно - [щ].

Т.В. Иванова в "Новом орфоэпическом словаре русского языка" приводит статью:

***умерщвле'ние, умерщвле'ния ... об умерщвле'нии***

Пометы [ш] нет.

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина!